# `spplot` doesn't respect `pointsize`

Tags: r, lattice

I am using pointsize to define the font size in the PNG output device. Here I set the pointsize to 24 - double of the default 12, to also have the font size in the PNG double of the default - but the font remains of the same size:

```
png('myfile.png', width = 1024, height = 640, pointsize=24)
spplot(...)
dev.off()
```

This approach normally works for all sorts of plots, but not for `spplot`. Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found a solution with `lattice.options`

```
require(lattice)
lattice.options(default.theme = list(fontsize = list(text = 24)))
png('myfile.png', width = 1024, height = 640)
spplot(...)
dev.off()
```